# understanding the javascript statement

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am not able to get what this statement does in java script.please explain it to me.

`url= "/rfp/AjaxCreateBuyer"`.

This below statement has been placed in master page file of an asp.net mvc project.

```
var Url = function (url) {
                var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
                return baseUrl + url.replace(/^\//, "");
            }
```

Thanks Much.

Comment: Which statement? There are half a dozen different ones there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It builds the url relative to the root of the site

Comment: i am such a stupid...wasted lot of time figuring it out instead of using it straight away.Thanks for effective answer -;)